# ggplot2: How do you change the colour of the background of the wsj theme?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm guessing that it is probably really easy, but I can't figure out how to change the background colour of the graph I made with `ggplot(...) + geom_line(...) + theme_wsj()`. It is now kind of yellowish and I would like to have it white.

I tried

```
+ theme_wsj(panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "white"))
```

but that gave an error :unused argument (panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "white"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try argument named `panel.background` inside `theme()` function and not `theme_wsj()`. An example is shown below

```
    + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "navy"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for the area where the graph is in! Around the graph is still yellowish though, but I'm guessing that I only have find a command to change that (instead of fill).

Comment: You might be having a legend inside I guess for your plot? If you plot the legend outside, then it would fill completely, otherwise we need to fill the legend background separately.

Comment: Yes, now the panel background and plot background are white, but the legend is not. I will fill the legend background seperately. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Not a problem. You can try combo of both `plot.background` and `panel.background`. Each area has its own functions and arguments. Especially legends irrespective of whether you are using `ggplot2` commands or basic r plot commands. Thank you.

Comment: `legend.background` to fill legend area and `legend.key` to fill individual levels inside legend. Use both of these inside `theme` function and fill them with color using `element_rect` function.

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling to find the command `legend.key` but now all of the elements are white :)

Comment: Great to know :) Good luck!!

Comment: Please, see `?ggplot2::theme` for a list of theme elements. See also the [ggplot doc site](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/) with tons of examples, in particular [`theme`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html).